# Monticello, is it possible to Save in more repositories at the same time?

Tags: git, smalltalk, squeak, monticello

I would like to keep a Squeak project updated in GitHub and Squeaksource at the same time.

I have Metacello-Git installed and working.

If I press Save in Monticello, say, first for GitHub and then for Squeaksource, I get 1 version made for each repository I Save.

I do not want that. In general, the version must be the same in all repositories.

Is this possible ?

Comment: If I understand you, what you want is the same copy at both places.  Why don't you save it to one and replicate it to other?

Comment: I don't know how to 'replicate'. I tried to `Save` in the two repositories, but doing that, the version number increases x2. And I need to write another time the same log comment. ... A few minutes ago i discovered that right clicking  an item on the repositories column one of the choices is `save repositorie*s*` . That plural at the end let me think maybe that is the way to go. I will try tomorrow !

Comment: By replication I meant pick a primary repository e.g. github and then have a script run periodically on any change to push it to squeaksource.  Usually you have a local repository from which you push the changes to any number of repositories.

Comment: I see. But still, I would really like to select multiple repositories and just press `Save`.  I don't think this feature is implemented in Squeak, but I guess i got how to make it. I must ask `basicStoreVersion` to each object `.*Repository` selected in the Monticello interface. Passing as parameter the same `aVersion` object ... I will try when i will be a bit more experienced;)

Comment: I see.  What I do not understand is why you want to do manually.  Is there a particular advantage or reason?

Answer (score 1):

After you open a repository in the Monticello Browser, if you select a package in the list on the left hand side and then a version on the right hand side, you can click the copy button. That opens a list of other repositories you can copy that same version to. So if you'd want that to happen automatically, you'd need to take a look in MCFileRepositoryInspector and its superclasses (see #save in MCVersionInspector)